# Insert data from CSV in one column and custom input in other columns with LOAD DATA INFILE in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, csv, date, sql-insert, load-data-infile

I have a pre-defined table (with data) in a MySQL database with 3 columns:

```
brandId INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
brand CHAR,
insertDateTime DATETIME
```

And I have a list of brands stored in a csv file (10,000 rows).

I want to insert the brands into the table as new rows, with `insertDateTime` shows the date time of the insertion.

I know I can use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load the brands from the csv, and I can use the `NOW()` function to compute insert datetime as we go, but how to combine them in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SET` clause of `LOAD DATA` to provide values that do not come from the input file.

Consider the following syntax:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'myfile.csv'
INTO TABLE mytable (brand)
SET insertDateTime = NOW();
```